# Python tkinter - button not appearing when placed at a coordinate

Tags: python, tkinter

There are three widgets that I'm trying to get into my tkinter GUI: A label, an entry, and a button. The issue however, is that the button isn't showing up when running the program. Here is my code:

```
windowFU = tk.Tk()
windowFU.title("MHFU Database")
windowFU.geometry("255x200+300+180")

icon = tk.PhotoImage(file = "images/icon.png")
windowFU.iconphoto(False, icon)

frame = tk.Frame(master = windowFU, width = 255, height = 200)
frame.pack()

welcome = tk.Label(

    master = frame,
    text = "What would you like to view?",
    width = 30,
    height = 2

)

searchEntry = tk.Entry(

    master = frame,
    width = 30

)

buttonMonstersFU = tk.Button(

    master = frame,
    text = "Monsters",
    width = 12,
    height = 2

)

welcome.pack()
searchEntry.pack()    
buttonMonstersFU.place(x = 100, y = 100)

searchEntry.bind('<Return>', getEntry)

windowFU.mainloop()
```

Here is what shows up:

[image: Here is what shows up].

Is this because I am using `.pack()` for the first two widgets, but `.place()` for the last one? I've tried using `.place()` for all 3 of them, and this is what comes up:

[image: this is what comes up].

Note that when I tried to use `.place()` for the other two widgets, I did not add any other parameters into the brackets.

What should I do?

Comment: line 42, in <module>
    searchEntry.bind('<Return>', getEntry)
NameError: name 'getEntry' is not defined. Did you mean: 'getattr'?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used `pack()` on the label and entry, so `frame` will be shrink to fit them.  Therefore the button is placed outside the visible area of `frame`.

You can either make `frame` to fill the available space of root window:

```
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

or disable resize of `frame` using `pack_propagate()`:

```
frame.pack_propagate(0)
```